# Searching substring in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a POstgreSQL 8.4.
I have a table and i want to find a string in one row (character varying datatype) of this table using substring (character varying datatype) returned by subquery:

```
SELECT  uchastki.kadnum
FROM  uchastki
WHERE kadnum LIKE (
    SELECT str
    FROM test
    WHERE str IS NOT NULL)
```

But get a error

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

In field  `test.str` i have strings like `66:07:21 01 001` in `uchastki.kadnum` `66:07:21 01 001:27`.

How to find substring using results of subquery?

**UPDATE**

Table test:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    str character varying(255)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE test OWNER TO postgres;
```

Table uchastki:

```
CREATE TABLE uchastki
(
    fid serial NOT NULL,
    the_geom geometry,
    id_uch integer,
    num_opora character varying,
    kod_lep integer,
    kadnum character varying,
    sq real,
    kod_type_opora character varying,
    num_f11s integer,
    num_opisanie character varying,
    CONSTRAINT uchastki_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fid),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE uchastki OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Recognise this familiar comment? "Please mention your PostgreSQL version". You know the drill by now. SQL (check), Error message (check), PostgreSQL version (nope), Schema or SQLFiddle (nope), sample data (nope). /frustrated

Comment: What exactly is stored in the column `test.str`? Can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `test.str` its a string just a string.

Comment: @Craig Ringer i think my question is a basic SQL.

Comment: @KliverMax There's no `string` data type. Do you mean `text`? `varchar`?

Comment: @KliverMax To me it's just considerate to put some effort in yourself, showing that you respect others' time. Of course that's purely my opinion, but it's in line with the site guidelines and FAQ. Also, while you think it's just basic SQL, *you're asking for help with it* so it might not be what you think. Consider reading the "How to ask better questions" section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `like any` :

```
SELECT  uchastki.kadnum
FROM  uchastki
WHERE kadnum LIKE  ANY(
   SELECT str
   FROM test
WHERE str IS NOT NULL)
```

Or perhaps:

```
SELECT  uchastki.kadnum
FROM  uchastki
WHERE kadnum LIKE  ANY(
   SELECT '%' || str || '%'
   FROM test
WHERE str IS NOT NULL)
```

this is a nice feature, You can use different operators, for example `= any (select ... )`, or `<> all (select...)`.

Comment: Nice guess at the poster's actual intentions. Will the second formulation with `LIKE ANY (...)` really work? If so, that's *cool*.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Yes, it will. Another nice example :  `... where tsvector_col @@ any(select tsquery_col...)`

Comment: Sure does. You learn something every day 'round here. Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fc538/1

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark and assume you mean that you want to match a string `Sa` from table `A` against one or more other strings `S1 .. Sn` from table `B` to find out if any of the other strings in `S1 .. Sn` is a substring of `Sa`.

A simple example to show what I mean (hint, hint):

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (string_a text);
INSERT INTO tableA(string_a) VALUES 
('the manual is great'), ('Chicken chicken chicken'), ('bork');

CREATE TABLE tableB(candidate_str text);
INSERT INTO tableB(candidate_str) VALUES
('man'),('great'),('chicken');
```

I want the result set:

```
the manual is great
chicken chicken chicken
```

because `the manual is great` has `man` and `great` in it; and because `chicken chicken chicken` has `chicken` in it. There is no need to show the substring(s) that matched. `bork` doesn't match any substring so it is not found.

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fc538/1) with the sample data.

If so, shamelessly stealing @maniek's excellent suggestion, you would use:

```
SELECT string_a 
FROM tableA 
WHERE string_a LIKE ANY (SELECT '%'||candidate_str||'%' FROM tableB);
```

(Vote for @maniek please, I'm just illustrating how to clearly explain - I hope - what you want to achieve, sample data, etc).

Comment: Sorry for quallity of my question.

Comment: @KliverMax It's OK the first few times, I just think you should know better by now. Please *think about it* before your next question.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: This answer was written before further discussion clarified the poster's actual intentions)

It would appear highly likely that there is more than one `str` in `test` where `str IS NOT NULL`. That's why more than one row is returned by the subquery used as an expression, and, thus, why the statement fails.

Run the subquery stand-alone to see what it returns and you'll see. Perhaps you intended it to be a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) but forgot the outer column-reference? Or perhaps there's a column also called `str` in the outer table and you meant to write:

```
SELECT  uchastki.kadnum
FROM  uchastki
WHERE kadnum LIKE (
SELECT test.str
FROM test
WHERE uchastki.str IS NOT NULL)
```

?

(*Hint: Consistently using table aliases on column references helps to avoid name-clash confusion)*.

Comment: Subquery returns ~200 results. its mean that i cant find a string using several substrings in Postgre?