# How to use SQL LIKE condition with multiple values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is there any shorter way to look for multiple matches:

```
 SELECT * 
 from table 
 WHERE column LIKE "AAA%" 
    OR column LIKE "BBB%" 
    OR column LIKE "CCC%"
```

This questions applies to PostgreSQL 9.1, but if there is a generic solution it would be even better.

Comment: It reads well, works well and is easy to understand. Why swap that for alternatives like the popular answer and get into knots when you need to find pipes (`|`) or brackets in actual data?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi Because is it not as easy to dynamically build. See my answer on how to avoid dealing with a regex.

Comment: @Clo It's still code that's not ISO standard and *harder* to understand by comparison. Except possibly `any (values('AAA%'), ('BBB%'), ('CCC%')` That one looks good.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Perhaps using `SIMILAR TO` would work ?

```
SELECT * from table WHERE column SIMILAR TO '(AAA|BBB|CCC)%';
```

Comment: +1 `SIMILAR TO` would work, but for the example in the question it should be `SIMILAR TO 'AAA%|(BBB|CCC)%'` or `SIMILAR TO '(AA%|BBB%|CCC%'`

Comment: `Similar to` was added to Postgres 7.3, so Netezza systems and the like may not allow its use.

Comment: Very elegant solution

Answer (score 43):

Use `LIKE ANY(ARRAY['AAA%', 'BBB%', 'CCC%'])` as per this cool trick [@maniek showed earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953273/398670).

Comment: You just missed the syntax. The list must be array or set.

Comment: I believe `ANY` was added in Postgres 7.4.

Answer (score 33):

Using array or set comparisons:

```
create table t (str text);
insert into t values ('AAA'), ('BBB'), ('DDD999YYY'), ('DDD099YYY');

select str from t
where str like any ('{"AAA%", "BBB%", "CCC%"}');

select str from t
where str like any (values('AAA%'), ('BBB%'), ('CCC%'));
```

It is also possible to do an `AND` which would not be easy with a regex if it were to match any order:

```
select str from t
where str like all ('{"%999%", "DDD%"}');

select str from t
where str like all (values('%999%'), ('DDD%'));
```

Comment: I believe `ANY` and `ALL` were added in Postgres 7.4.

Answer (score 15):

You can use regular expression operator (**~**), separated by (**|**) as described in [Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html)

```
select column_a from table where column_a ~* 'aaa|bbb|ccc'
```

Answer (score 6):

Following query helped me. Instead of using `LIKE`, you can use `~*`.

```
select id, name from hosts where name ~* 'julia|lena|jack';
```

Answer (score -5):

You might be able to use IN, if you don't actually need wildcards.

SELECT * 
 from table 
 WHERE column IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')