# SQL like for comma separated input

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write a stored procedure in which I want to run a query for multiple input which comes as a comma separated string. Just like we have `in` for exact match, can I have something `like in` too?

Input:

```
51094,51096,512584
```

Attempting to do:

```
select * from table where column like ('%51094%','%51096%','%512584%')
```

My query should iterate through each input and get the column which matches the pattern.

I have already tried following:

```
Contains(Column, '"*51094*" or "*51096*" or "*512584*")
```

But can't configure freetext search now.

Source: [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

All the proposed types in: [How to use SQL LIKE condition with multiple values in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957993/how-to-use-sql-like-condition-with-multiple-values-in-postgresql)

None seems to be working.

Please suggest a simple way.

Comment: Is this MySQL or MS SQL Server? You currently have both tags.

Comment: have a look at this thread, might help you:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

Try with first explode your input

```
$arr = explode($Input,",");
column like "%".$arr[0]."%" OR
column like "%".$arr[1]."%" OR
column like "%".$arr[2]."%"
```

Comment: The length is not fixed. It can be as long as 600 to 700 entries. I can't write your solution for such a case.

Answer (score 0):

This function you can use, no any mandatory to give comma only you can give special character.

ALTER function [dbo].[SplitString] (@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))
Returns @Results Table (Items nvarchar(50))
As
Begin
Declare @Index int
Declare @name nvarchar(20)
Declare @Slice nvarchar(50)

Select @Index = 1
If @String Is NULL Return

While @Index != 0
Begin
Select @Index = CharIndex(@Delimiter, @String)
If @Index <> 0

Select @Slice = left(@String, @Index - 1)

else

Select @Slice = @String
Insert into @Results(Items) Values (@Slice)
Select @String = right(@String, Len(@String) - @Index)

If Len(@String) = 0 break

End
Return
End

Answer (score 0):

Looped the items and got it done.

```
Select * into #temp_inputIds from dbo.Split(@InputIds,',')

    DECLARE @ID varchar (50)
    DECLARE IDs CURSOR LOCAL FOR select items from #temp_inputIds

    OPEN IDs
    FETCH NEXT FROM IDs into @ID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN



    Select @SQL = 'Select component_id,'+@ID+' as pub_id from component_presentations where CONTENT like ''%' + @ID + '%'''



    FETCH NEXT FROM IDs into @ID
    END

    CLOSE IDs
    DEALLOCATE IDs
```