# Alternative solution for multiple LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make multiple like in the clause like this code but I need to shorten it because I have to repeat this code for several different conditions to create different tables. I have tried all of the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957993/how-to-use-sql-like-condition-with-multiple-values-in-postgresql) but somehow none of this works for me. I have also tried `LIKE '[40101,40102,40104]%'` and  `LIKE '[40101-40102-40104]%'` but it did not work too. What should I do?

```
SELECT * 
 from table 
 WHERE column LIKE '40101%' 
    OR column LIKE '40102%' 
    OR column LIKE '40105%'
```

Comment: SQL Server does not use double quotes for strings, so your query is a little confusing.

Comment: The [Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For these patterns you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE '4010[125]%'
```

SQL Server modestly extends `LIKE` patterns to include character matching.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what if the patterns are `40101,40102,40105,10901,10701,20101,30109` ?

Comment: @littlesheep . . . That would be a different question and should be asked as a *new* question,