# How to query only the data that has emojis (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, emoji

I have data that contains emojis within a database column, i.e.

```
message_text
-------


Hi
```

I want to query only the rows that have data containing emojis. Is there a simple way to do this in postgres?

```
select data from table where data_col contains emoji
```

Currently I use a simple query

```
select message_text from cb_messages_v1 cmv
 where message_text IN ('','','','', '')
```

but I want it to be more dynamic, where if future emotions are added it will capture the data.

Comment: The same way you would search for filed containing single character "A" or "B" or ... Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957993/how-to-use-sql-like-condition-with-multiple-values-in-postgresql

Comment: @O-9 that is helpful, but I what if a new emoji character is introduced? i would have to update my code and include it. Is there a way to do this without having to hard code a list of all possible emojis?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From your example it seems like you are not only interested in *emoticons* (U+1F601 - U+1F64F), but also in *Miscellaneous Symbols And Pictographs* (U+1F300 - U+1F5FF) and *Transport And Map Symbols* (U+1F680 - U+1F6C5).

You can find values that contain one of these with

```
WHERE textcol ~ '[\U0001F300-\U0001F6FF]'
```

`~` is the regular expression matching operator, and the pattern is a range of Unicode characters.

Comment: Oh wow... so simple. No need for my long answer anymore :D Thanks, lesson learned.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do the same in python, as well?

Comment: Just like that - SQL is SQL.

Comment: FYI, this doesn't support all emojis. For instance, the flag emojis aren't detected by the regex.

Comment: @pir Well, [these](https://unicode-table.com/en/emoji/#link-flags) are. But I guess this is a moving target. I have extended the range to 1F6FF.