# Searching substring in PostgreSQL (part II)

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

**I've found this** [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953404/3086147) :

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (string_a text);
INSERT INTO tableA(string_a) VALUES 
('the manual is great'), ('Chicken chicken chicken'), ('bork');

CREATE TABLE tableB(candidate_str text);
INSERT INTO tableB(candidate_str) VALUES
('man'),('great'),('chicken');

SELECT string_a 
FROM tableA 
WHERE string_a LIKE ANY (SELECT '%'||candidate_str||'%' FROM tableB);
```

Result :

```
the manual is great
chicken chicken chicken
```

**Question : 
How to do to have this new result ?**

```
the manuel is great      | great
chicken chicken chicken  | chicken
```

Comment: Please define *which* row to pick from `tableB` in case of multiple matches. Also, do you expect *few* or *many* matches per row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JOIN:

```
SELECT a.string_a, b.candidate_str
FROM tableA a
  JOIN tableB b ON a.string_a LIKE '%'||b.candidate_str||'%';
```

Note that this will show the row with `the manual is great` twice, because the `candidate_str` matches the `man` in `manual` and the word `great`. This could be changed by e.g. using `distinct on` to only return rows from `tableA` once.

Comment: Do note that you are using a front *and* back wildcard with LIKE. This will destroy any index usage, which is a bad idea. Why not use PostgreSQLs full text search capabilities for this instead?

Comment: @Timusan: that is a valid point but you should have addressed that to leasye Btw: there *is* an index type in Postgres that can be used with such a LIKE condition: http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Ah, sorry about that, must still be sleeping, did not see the wildcards in the original query. Hmm, that index type is indeed news to me (thanks for the heads-up), sounds tempting, but still prefer FTS in Leasye's case.